# how to get row between two records?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

i need to retrieve row between empid=1 to next empid=1?

```
empid empname
1   a
2   b
3   c
1   d
2   e
4   f
3   g   
32  h
1   i
```

Output like this

```
empid empname
2       b
3       c
```

Comment: Rows have no order in (my)SQL, so unless empname is consistently arranged alphabetically, this problem is technically insoluble.

Comment: The problem is not clear to me..

Comment: Don't you need to specify between `empid=1 AND empname=a` to "next" empid=1 because there is also a between for `empid=1 AND empname=d` and `empid=1 AND empname=i`.